# How to get selected radio button value in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

I have a lot of radio buttons named after numbers between 0 and 20. And pretty much the same code to run when they're selected. If I could somehow use something like "checkedRadioButton.value" things would be a lot easier.

I have some pictures to show, when radiobutton1 is selected picture1 will be shown. I get the pictures with

```
OpenFileDialog1.Multiselect = True
OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
```

and want to use something like

```
PictureBox1.ImageLocation = OpenFileDialog1.FileNames(checkedRadioButton.value)
```

Comment: That seems slightly odd because the second code snippet seems to assume that the user selected the same number of files as there are `RadioButtons`. Are you creating the `RadioButtons` after the files are selected, so the numbers are guaranteed to match? If so, why not use the principle in my answer below but actually assign the file path to the `Tag` property? Not much point storing one value to get another when you can store the actual value you want in the first place.

Comment: Yes, they are guaranteed to match. I have test questions as images and there are 20 of them. First radio button is selected, first question appears.

Comment: Please see the update to my answer.

Comment: @jmcilhinney it helped a lot, thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to set the `Tag` property of each control to the associated value. `Tag` is a general-purpose property intended to store arbitrary data, so you can use it for whatever you like. It is type `Object`, so you'll need to cast whatever you get from it. To get the associated `Integer` value from the checked `RadioButton` on the form you could do this:

```vb
Dim number = CInt(Me.Controls.OfType(Of RadioButton)().First(Function(rb) rb.Checked).Tag)
```

If your `RadioButtons` are in some other container, e.g. a `Panel` or `GroupBox`, then you must use that container's `Controls` collection instead.

EDIT:

As the end game here seems to be to get a file path, it would make sense to assign the file path to the `Tag` property in the first place. You can then get the file path directly from the `RadioButton`, e.g.

```vb
PictureBox1.ImageLocation = CStr(Me.Controls.OfType(Of RadioButton)().First(Function(rb) rb.Checked).Tag)
```

Another option is to create your own derived control and add a dedicated property, e.g.

```vb
Public Class FilePathRadioButton
    Inherits RadioButton

    Public Property FilePath As String

End Class
```

You can then use that class instead of the standard `RadioButton` class and use the `FilePath` property instead of the `Tag` property. There's then no need for a cast:

```vb
PictureBox1.ImageLocation = Me.Controls.OfType(Of RadioButton)().First(Function(rb) rb.Checked).FilePath
```